# Writing Name From ArrayList to XML File

Tags: java, xml, class

I am trying to write the names of the passengers in an ArrayList to an XML file. I have to put the code for the XML document creation into my Aircraft class. Below is both my code for the Aircraft class. This also includes my code for the main calling method App.java. There are no errors in either of these classes; however, part of me thinks that it is not correctly creating the XML file. I was wondering if I have to call the writeNames() method anywhere in the App.java for it to work correctly?

Aircraft Class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class Aircraft {

    private double maxSpeed;
    private int maxPassengers;
    private int numEngines;

    private Pilot pilot;
    private Stewardess stewardess;
    private ArrayList<Passenger> passengers;

    Aircraft(double maxSpeed, int maxPassengers, int numEngines, Pilot pilot, 
        Stewardess stewardess, ArrayList<Passenger> passengers)
{
    this.pilot = pilot;
    this.stewardess = stewardess;
    this.passengers = passengers;
    this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
    this.maxPassengers = maxPassengers;
    this.numEngines = numEngines;
}

public String getInfo()
{
    return "Aircraft" + "\n" + "Max Speed: " + this.maxSpeed + " mph " + "\n" + 
           "Max Passengers: " + this.maxPassengers + " passengers " + "\n" + "Number of Engines: " + 
           this.numEngines + " engines" + "\n" + "\n" + this.pilot.getInfo() + "\n" + "\n" + "Stewardess" 
           + this.stewardess.getInfo() + "\n" + "\n" + "Passenger 1" + passengers.get(0).getInfo() + "\n"+ "\n" + "Passenger 2" 
           + passengers.get(1).getInfo() + "\n" + "\n" + "Passenger 3" + passengers.get(2).getInfo() + "\n" + "\n" + "Passenger 4" 
           + passengers.get(3).getInfo();
}

public ArrayList<String> writeNames(ArrayList<String> passengers)
{
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder;            

        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.newDocument();
        Element xmlRoot = document.createElement("Passengers");
        document.appendChild(xmlRoot);

        Element passenger;
        Element name;

        //passenger1
        passenger = document.createElement("Passenger");
        passenger.setAttribute("id", "1");

        name = document.createElement("Name");
        name.appendChild(document.createTextNode(passengers.get(0)));
        passenger.appendChild(name);

        xmlRoot.appendChild(passenger);

        //passenger2
        passenger = document.createElement("Passenger");
        passenger.setAttribute("id", "2");

        name = document.createElement("Name");
        name.appendChild(document.createTextNode(passengers.get(1)));
        passenger.appendChild(name);

        xmlRoot.appendChild(passenger);

        //passenger3
        passenger = document.createElement("Passenger");
        passenger.setAttribute("id", "3");

        name = document.createElement("Name");
        name.appendChild(document.createTextNode(passengers.get(2)));
        passenger.appendChild(name);

        xmlRoot.appendChild(passenger);

        //passenger4
        passenger = document.createElement("Passenger");
        passenger.setAttribute("id", "4");

        name = document.createElement("Name");
        name.appendChild(document.createTextNode(passengers.get(3)));
        passenger.appendChild(name);

        xmlRoot.appendChild(passenger);            

        //Write document to file
        TransformerFactory transFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes"); 
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult("src/passengers.xml");
        transformer.transform(source, result);            

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return passengers;
}
```

}

App.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Four roommates that share same address, have different suitcases, traveling to different destinations
    Address address = new Address("University Park", "PA", "16802");        
    Suitcase suitcase1 = new Suitcase(7, 75, "Carry Strap");
    Suitcase suitcase2 = new Suitcase(5, 70, "No Carry Strap");
    Suitcase suitcase3 = new Suitcase(4, 60, "No Carry Strap");
    Suitcase suitcase4 = new Suitcase(8, 55, "Carry Strap");

    //Stewardess Info
    Suitcase suitcaseStewardess = new Suitcase(4, 40, "No Carry Strap");
    Address addressStewardess = new Address("Doylestown", "PA", "18902");
    Stewardess stewardess = new Stewardess(4, "Full Time", 40, suitcaseStewardess, addressStewardess);

    //Pilot Info
    Suitcase suitcasePilot = new Suitcase(10, 50, "Carry Strap");
    Address addressPilot = new Address("Raliegh", "NC", "27513");
    Map map = new Map(14000.5, "United States", "Northeast");
    Pilot pilot = new Pilot(7, 40, "Perfect", suitcasePilot, map, addressPilot);

    //Passenger Info
    ArrayList<Passenger> passengers = new ArrayList<>();
    passengers.add(new Passenger("Luke Harding", 1400, "England", "First Class - A14", suitcase1, address));
    passengers.add(new Passenger("Dalton Sydnor", 1000, "Mexico", "First Class - G7", suitcase2, address));
    passengers.add(new Passenger("Ian Smithgall", 700, "Russia", "First Class - C4", suitcase3, address));
    passengers.add(new Passenger("Matt Yohe", 850, "Indiana", "First Class - B1", suitcase4, address));

    //Aircraft Info
    Aircraft aircraft = new Aircraft (750, 400, 4, pilot, stewardess, passengers);

    System.out.println(aircraft.getInfo());  
}
```

}

Comment: Why not use JAXB which would allow more fluent translation from object to XML and back again?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have not learned how to do that yet

Comment: Crazy, consider looking it up. It's rather flexible, powerful and just plain nifty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, based off the code you provided, if you want to write the passengers to an XML file, you will need to call the Aircraft's writePassengers method and pass in the list of passengers you would like to write.

This doesn't seem to make sense since you are setting the list of passengers locally when you create the class and still requiring it as a parameter in the method. You should be able to remove the parameter and still have proper functionality:

```
public ArrayList<String> writeNames()
```

then you can call the function in your App class like below after the Airplane class has been created:

```
aircraft.writeNames()
```

Comment: I see what you're saying, I tried doing this. However, when I do this, it then causes an error in these lines: name.appendChild(document.createTextNode(passengers.get(0)));

Comment: I haven't used these libraries to create an XML document, but I am assuming the error is caused by you passing passenger.get(0) which returns an object of type Passenger. I would try returning a String. I think your passenger.get(0).getInfo() might accomplish this.

Additionally, I hadn't looked too much at your write method, but I see now that you have hardcoded everything. As you can see, you have written the same lines of code for each passenger in this method. Instead, you should iterate through a collection to reduce the number of lines of code you have to write.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for the help. I am currently away from my computer, but I will try your suggestions and come back if I have any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Again, if this were my problem, I'd use JAXB to marshall my Java classes to XML and back again, since this takes all the fidgety parts of having to manually create the XML document out of your hands and into the libraries.

- Intro tutorial: [Lesson: Introduction to JAXB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/)
- In depth tutorial: [Project JAXB](https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/)

To use ArrayLists you'd annotate them with the `@XmlElementWrapper` annotation.

For instance if you had a class room class with a teacher field a maxStudent field, a maxStudents field, you could create your classes with JAXB annotations, like so:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "person")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Person { // base class
    @XmlElement(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @XmlElement(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Person() {
        // Default constructors are required
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + "]";
    }

}
```

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "teacher")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Teacher extends Person {
    @XmlElement(name = "grade_level")
    private String gradeLevel;

    public Teacher(String firstName, String lastName, String gradeLevel) {
        super(firstName, lastName);
        this.gradeLevel = gradeLevel;
    }

    public Teacher() {
        // Default constructors are required
    }

    public String getGradeLevel() {
        return gradeLevel;
    }

    public void setGradeLevel(String gradeLevel) {
        this.gradeLevel = gradeLevel;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Teacher [gradeLevel=" + gradeLevel + ", getFirstName()=" + getFirstName() + ", getLastName()="
                + getLastName() + "]";
    }

}
```

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "student")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Student extends Person {
    @XmlElement(name = "age")
    private int age;

    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
        super(firstName, lastName);
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Student() {

    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [age=" + age + ", getFirstName()=" + getFirstName() + ", getLastName()=" + getLastName() + "]";
    }

}
```

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "class_room")
@XmlType(propOrder = {"teacher", "maxStudents", "students"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class ClassRoom {
    @XmlElementRef
    private Teacher teacher;
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "students")
    @XmlElement(name = "student")
    private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
    @XmlElement(name = "max_students")
    int maxStudents;

    public ClassRoom(Teacher teacher, int maxStudents) {
        this.teacher = teacher;
        this.maxStudents = maxStudents;
    }

    public ClassRoom() {

    }

    public void addStudent(Student student) {
        students.add(student);
    }

    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }

    public Teacher getTeacher() {
        return teacher;
    }

    public int getMaxStudents() {
        return maxStudents;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClassRoom [teacher=" + teacher + ", students=" + students + ", maxStudents=" + maxStudents + "]";
    }

}
```

And then marshal them to XML simply via few bits of code:

```
// create and fill my class room
ClassRoom classRoom = new ClassRoom(new Teacher("John", "Smith", "Four"), 30);
classRoom.addStudent(new Student("Bill", "Jones", 11));
classRoom.addStudent(new Student("Cathy", "Franks", 12));
classRoom.addStudent(new Student("Henry", "Rotter", 11));
classRoom.addStudent(new Student("Barry", "Edwards", 11));
classRoom.addStudent(new Student("Daffy", "Duck", 10));
classRoom.addStudent(new Student("Mickey", "Mouse", 11));
classRoom.addStudent(new Student("Donald", "Trump", 11));

try {
    // marshall to XML
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ClassRoom.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marshaller.marshal(classRoom, System.out);
} catch (JAXBException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<class_room>
    <teacher>
        <first_name>John</first_name>
        <last_name>Smith</last_name>
        <grade_level>Four</grade_level>
    </teacher>
    <max_students>30</max_students>
    <students>
        <student>
            <first_name>Bill</first_name>
            <last_name>Jones</last_name>
            <age>11</age>
        </student>
        <student>
            <first_name>Cathy</first_name>
            <last_name>Franks</last_name>
            <age>12</age>
        </student>
        <student>
            <first_name>Henry</first_name>
            <last_name>Rotter</last_name>
            <age>11</age>
        </student>
        <student>
            <first_name>Barry</first_name>
            <last_name>Edwards</last_name>
            <age>11</age>
        </student>
        <student>
            <first_name>Daffy</first_name>
            <last_name>Duck</last_name>
            <age>10</age>
        </student>
        <student>
            <first_name>Mickey</first_name>
            <last_name>Mouse</last_name>
            <age>11</age>
        </student>
        <student>
            <first_name>Donald</first_name>
            <last_name>Trump</last_name>
            <age>11</age>
        </student>
    </students>
</class_room>
```